# Get GCP Logging Log Viewer to highlight custom labels

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

A great feature in debugging Google Cloud Functions calls is the highlighting of the functionName and the execution id (see photo). Is it possible to also get your own logs (generated by the python logging client) to show up highlighted?

[image]

Comment: One solution is to note use the client library, and simply format print statements according to the format in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging

Comment: Hi, is this solution the one that works for you? If so, could you post it as a solution and accept it so it helps the community members?

Comment: @asbovelw Actually no, the above that I posted did not work. I created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/googleapis/python-functions/issues/10

Answer (score 3):

You can use summary fields to show these values

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface#add_summary_fields

[image]

Comment: Is that a global setting or visible only by myself?